# question regarding metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

let X be the surface of the earth for any two points on the earth surface. let d(a,b) be the least time needed to travel from a to b.is this the metric on X? kindly explain each step and logic, specially for these two axioms d(a,b)=0 iff a=b and triangle inequality.

Comment: d(a,b) iff a=b is trivial

Answer (score 2):

This will generally not be a metric since the condition of symmetry is not fulfilled: It usually takes a different time to travel from $a$ to $b$ than to travel from $b$ to $a$. (I know that because I live on a hill. :-)

The remaining conditions are fulfilled:

- The time required to travel from $a$ to $b$ is non-negative.
- The time required to travel from $a$ to $b$ is zero if and only if $a=b$.
- $d(a,c)\le d(a,b)+d(b,c)$ since you can always travel first from $a$ to $b$ and then from $b$ to $c$ in order to travel from $a$ to $c$.

Comment: Such is called *quasimetric*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semimetric_space#Quasimetrics

Comment: @Berci: Great -- the Wikipedia article even mentions travelling up hill :-)